# Angular CLI проблема с установкой

Tags: angular, npm

После команды npm install -g @angular/cli, устанавливаются файлы и все проходит отлично, но после команды ng new, или просто ng выводит ошибку Unknown error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read. В чем может быть проблема. Node Js переустановил, npm так же, разрешение также для чтение и изменение в род файлах, OC Windows 8

Comment: как вы проверяли, что все хорошо? (имею ввиду после установки)

Comment: После установки текст по типу что ангуляр установлен версии 9 https://pastenow.ru/78d2e7ae053eb507a85b675731f66979 ссылка на скрин